# Linq to SQL Join, Order by, Group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I have the following sql query, which works fine. I want to convert this query to Linq.

```
select a.store_id, b.name 
from stock a inner join store b on a.store_id = b.id 
group by a.store_id, b.name 
order by a.store_id desc;
```

---

id | store_name

1  | A store

2  | B store

3  | C store

---

thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by order the grouped result. Can you provide an example of a few rows of the data you have and the output you expect? What are you trying to use the group by for?

Comment: What is the `order`you need? whats wrong with the current query?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. Just, I want to convert this query to Linq

Comment: From what I can tell, this query is kind of pointless, since you're ordering on and displaying the `store_id` from the stock table, when it's the same thing as the `id` in the store table. An identical way of writing it would be `SELECT id, name FROM store ORDER BY id`, is this what you're trying to achieve or were you wanting to do something with the stock table? - **Edit** saw you're comment above, don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code,

```
from a in stock
join b in store on a.store_id equals b.id
group new { a.store_id, b.name } by g into groupResult
orderby groupResult.store_id desc
select new 
{
    StoreId = groupResult.store_id, 
    Name = groupResult.name
}
```